# PowerShell - How to make a variable which is declared in a function inside a module, available to the calling script

Tags: powershell, variables, module, scope

I have a script which imports a module and runs a function in the module.
My problem is being able to access the value of a variable set in the module function. ie. to make a variable which is declared in a function inside a module, available to the calling script.

The code in my function in the module is:

```
Function TestFunction
{
$Script:setVarReturn = "Hello"
Write-Host ("Value of setVarReturn inside module function is " + $setVarReturn)
}
```

The script which calls this module function is:

```
Import-Module -Name 'E:\Data\Computing\Software\Programming\Scripts\dev\DS_ModMisc_dev.psm1'
Clear-Host
TestFunction
Write-Host ("Value of setVarReturn inside script is " + $setVarReturn)
```

The result I get is:

[image: Console message]

As you can see the script sees the variable as null.

As you can see I have, in desperation, even though I know it wont make any difference, given the variable a Script scope
It seems to be a simple request, can anyone recommend a simple solution?

Comment: You could use parameters in your function DS_ModMisc_dev.psm1 — and pass the variable to the function.

Comment: @LightningWar, I think what you suggest would work if I were trying to pass a value to the function in the module. But I am trying to pass a value from a function in a module to a script which calls the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options I see you have are either set your variable to the `$global:` scope instead of `$script:` so the variable is visible by all scopes (including the caller's):

```
New-Module -Name tempModule1 -ScriptBlock {
    function TestFunction {
        $global:setVarReturn = 'Hello'
        Write-Host ('Value of setVarReturn inside module function is ' + $setVarReturn)
    }
} | Import-Module

# Call the function
tempModule1\TestFunction
# Check variable, should output `Hello`
$setVarReturn

# Cleanup temp module and variable
Remove-Module tempModule1
Remove-Variable setVarReturn
```

Or use the `$script:` scope as you have it right now, which sets the variable in your Module's scope but its not visible by the caller, then you can retrieve that variable by accessing the Module's scope:

```
New-Module -Name tempModule2 -ScriptBlock {
    function TestFunction {
        $script:setVarReturn = 'Hello'
        Write-Host ('Value of setVarReturn inside module function is ' + $setVarReturn)
    }
} | Import-Module

# Call the function
tempModule2\TestFunction
# Check variable in the Module's scope, should output `Hello`
& (Get-Module tempModule2) { $setVarReturn }

# Cleanup temp module and variable
Remove-Module tempModule2
Remove-Variable setVarReturn
```

Or, set it as an Environment Variable (`$env:`):

```
New-Module -Name tempModule3 -ScriptBlock {
    function TestFunction {
        $env:setVarReturn = 'Hello'
        Write-Host ('Value of setVarReturn inside module function is ' + $env:setVarReturn)
    }
} | Import-Module

# Call the function
tempModule3\TestFunction
# Check the env var
$env:setVarReturn

# Cleanup temp module and env variable
Remove-Module tempModule3
Remove-Item env:setVarReturn
```

For options 1 and 3 you should note that you're altering the caller's session state and doing so is not the most common practice, in other words, you should have a very specific need for doing so or think if there is a better way to do what you're looking for. Also more relevant documentation can be found in [**about Scopes**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2) and [**about Environment Variables**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables).

---

Perhaps another option using a module variable and exporting it with [`Export-ModuleMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember?view=powershell-7.3):

```
New-Module -Name tempModule4 -ScriptBlock {
    $myRefVar = ''
    function TestFunction {
        ([ref] $myRefVar).Value = 'Hello'
        Write-Host ('Value of myRefVar inside module function is ' + $myRefVar)
    }

    Export-ModuleMember -Variable myRefvar -Function TestFunction
} | Import-Module

# Check empty var
$myRefVar
# Call the function
tempModule4\TestFunction
# Check var again, should be `Hello`
$myRefVar

# We can see the Module variable here
(Get-Module tempModule4).ExportedVariables

# Cleanup temp module
Remove-Module tempModule4
```

Comment: PowerShell modules seem to have been invented and recommended as a home for functions etc which can be called by many scripts. Also recommended to make scripts shorter and easier to follow by removing the inline functions to a module.
If that is so then when the language was developed and modules invented, surely the inventors also developed a way of obtaining the values of variables processed in functions in a module.  But apparently not, since the solutions above seem to be work-arounds. 
Am I misunderstanding the purpose of modules and maybe should not be using them?

Comment: Santiago, your option 1, using global scope does work so I have a solution. However you warn against using 'global' scope because it 'alters the caller's session state' (I will need to look that up; I am not familiar with the concept of session state yet.

Comment: @Davy its not that altering the users session state is something bad but is something the users should be aware of (sort of) perhaps i'm exaggerating but imagine the user of your module has a variable `$foo` defined in their session and when they import your module which also happens to use `$foo` they no longer have the value they're used to but the one you have decided to use, see how this could be a problem without consent or warning, you're affecting the users session in some way. It is not a common practice but whenever there is a need for this, and some cases there is